# How to sort a entity type field (without using query_builder option) in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I need to custom sort **[entity type](http://symfony.com/it/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)** field, but without `query_builder` option. I need to sort it based on some information not available at database-level (hence, not using the `query_builder`).

Is there a way I can sort the elements of the `<select>` widget?

**EDIT**: I have a `parent` self-association in my `section` table, which contains also a `title` property:

```
+--------------+-----------+--------+
| section_id   | parent_id | title  |
+--------------+-----------+--------+
|            1 |      NULL | Parent |
+--------------+-----------+--------+
|            2 |          1| Child  |
+--------------+-----------+--------+
|            3 |          2| Nephew |
+--------------+-----------+--------+
```

I'd like to show a select box where items are sorted by a concatenation of its title and ancerstor's titles, i.e:

```
Parent
Parent/Child
Parent/Child/nephew
```

Not easy to accomplish with a single SQL select, so I need a way to get the options and simple sort by this "path".

Comment: where are the information of sorting?

Answer (score 7):

You can default sort a relationship in the entity by doing this:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
 * @OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 **/
private $groups;
```

More info: [Ordering To-Many Associations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/tutorials/ordered-associations.html)

Comment: Yep I know, but It's not enought. I have a `parent` self-association in my `section` table, which contains also a `title` property. I'd like to show a select box where items are sorted by a concatenation of its title and ancerstor's titles (i.e. Parent/Child/Nepew). Not easy to accomplish with a single SQL select.

Comment: Fyi, unfortunately, the link to the tutorial is dead.

Comment: Thanks @soundlake. I've updated the response.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the OP correctly, the sorting is merely for displaying the select options in order for the user's benefit.

Add a function to your form type like this:

```
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    usort($view->children['select']->children, function(FormView $a, FormView $b) {
        return strcasecmp($a->vars['value']->getFullTitle(), $b->vars['value']->getFullTitle());
    });
}
```

This example assumes a `getFullTitle()` function exists on your entity which can generated the value to use for sorting comparisons. `select` would be the fieldName of the relationship the select box will be based on.

**5 Years later...**

Trying my own solution again in Symfony 4, this doesn't seem to work.

This is the solution that did work:

```
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    usort($view->children['select']->vars['choices'], function(ChoiceView $a, ChoiceView $b) {
        return strcasecmp($a->label, $b->label);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to add a "path" field on your section. And as soon as you call `$parent->addChild($child)` I would set the `$child->path` to `$parent->path . $child->path`. This is the only way if you want to filter within sql.

You could also consider using the Tree extension that uses nested sets in order to improve performance on this kind of operations:
https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md